# Bootstrap modal target content not showing in modal body in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jquery 1.8.3 and Bootstrap v2.3.2.

Issue is that content from target url is not showing in model-body.
This works fine in all browser except IE8.

Below is my code

*jquery*

```
   $(document).on('click', '.myModal', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        var title = $(this).attr("title");        
        $("#myModal .modal-body").html('Loading ........');
        $("#myModal").modal("show"); 
        $("#myModal .modal-body").load(target, function () {

        });
    });
```

*HTML*

```
<a href='http://test/test.php' class='myModal' title='Car page'>Pop up </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this meta tag to your header and try again ;

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"></meta>
```

if it doesn't work try this ;

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```